# Android: Move Fragment and add to backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a two pane layout.

I have a fragment on the left and a fragment on the right. Now I want to replace the left with the one on the right and create a new one on the right (i.e. I want to *move* the one on the right to the left, and create a new one on the right):

```
private FragmentManager fm; // assigned in onCreate
private MyListFragment rightSide; // assigned in onCreate

public void onClicked(Fragment fragment) { // callback
  fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.left_side, rightSide).commit();

  leftSide = rightSide;

  rightSide = MyListFragment.newInstance();
  fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.right_side, rightSide).commit();
}
```

Now at this point I get a `IllegalStateException`:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment MyListFragment{300c6aae #1 id=0x7f070094}: was 2131165332 now 2131165331
```

Well I can circumvent this situation by

```
fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, fm.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
fm.beginTransaction().remove(rightSide).commit();
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

But I also want to have the ability to add it to the back stack. When I press back I would like to remove the one on the right and move the one from the left back to the right.

How can I make one transaction out of this with the ability to add it to the backstack and revert the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Do it all in one transaction, then call `addToBackStack()` to undo the whole thing when you press the back button:

```
private FragmentManager fm; // assigned in onCreate
private MyListFragment rightSide; // assigned in onCreate

public void onClicked(Fragment fragment) { // callback

    MyListFragment newRightSide = MyListFragment.newInstance();

    fm.beginTransaction()
        .remove(rightSide)
        .replace(R.id.left_side, rightSide)
        .replace(R.id.right_side, newRightSide)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
}
```